# Choose which mainClass to use with sbt-native-packager

Tags: sbt, sbt-native-packager

I'm using sbt-native-packager 0.7.0-RC3 to package some of my application and many times I need to package with another mainClass.

When in dev mod i use this :

```
mainClass in (Compile, run) := Some("package.blabla.Dev")
```

And when packaging i want to use this :

```
mainClass in Debian := Some("package.blabla.Prod")
```

I try with "in Debian" but it don't work.

Is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [this pull request](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/pull/319) you can start choose a main class which should be started. Just add **-main your.production.Main** to *src/templates/etc-default* and enable the java_server archetype.